# How to thread process recording audio in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, audio

I am using the `AudioRecord` object, and within `AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener` I am implementing `AudioRecord.read` to write data to a byte buffer, after this I am calling another object's method to process the byte buffer and return it afterwards to write to file, the problem is the object's processing is quite long and seems to be stopping the main thread,which is odd i thought the `AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener` was Threaded

Answer (score 0):

Unless it explicitly says so, assume nothing is threaded in android.  Its all callbacks on the UI thread.

The normal way to do this would be to start up a thread in onCreate or onStart of your app, and have it wait for a message from the main thread.  Your implementation of onMarkerRead (or whatever other function you need) would then send a message to that thread.  You could create a thread whenever the notification function is called, but keeping the thread around avoids thread creation overhead at the OS level every time you get a notification.

Avoid using AsyncTasks here.  They sound like the right solution, but since all app tasks are single threaded they could be held up indefinitely.